# Group By Statement SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

This Select Statement Gives a Number of:

-Same CatCode

-Same CatName

But with Different Sales_Amt

```
Select p.CatCode, p.CatName, s.Sales_Amt
From A3_Dw_Prod p, A3_Dw_Sales s
Order By p.Dw_Prod_Id Desc;
```

I would Like to use Sum Function to add the these Categories and Group Them
When I use Sum I get an Error

*ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression*

```
Select p.CatCode, p.CatName, Sum(s.Sales_Amt)
From A3_Dw_Prod p, A3_Dw_Sales s
Where p.Dw_Prod_Id = s.Dw_Prod_Id
Group By p.CatCode, p.CatName 
Order By p.Dw_Prod_Id Desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the column 'p.Dw_Prod_Id Desc' is not in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises as you have included the " p.Dw_Prod_Id" in the ORDER BY clause
However, this column has not been selected in the main query so it creates problem
Put in ORDER BY one of the columns that is in the select clause(p.CatCode, p.CatName)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all those column in selection also that you are using in group by OR order by clause.

```
Select p.CatCode, p.CatName, p.Dw_Prod_Id, Sum(s.Sales_Amt)
From A3_Dw_Prod p, A3_Dw_Sales s
Where p.Dw_Prod_Id = s.Dw_Prod_Id
Group By p.CatCode, p.CatName,p.Dw_Prod_Id
Order By p.Dw_Prod_Id Desc, p.CatCode, p.CatName;
```